# RSA SSH2 Private Key issue using Jsch and Sshj in Java

Tags: java, ssh, bouncycastle, jsch, sshj

Here i am trying to connect to Remote Machine to do file transfer through `SFTP`. We are using `RSA SSH2 key` based authentication while connecting to remote machine.

I Tried doing this in below 2 approaches, i am facing issue with both the approaches.

**Approach 1:** Using [JSCH](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/)

```
JSch jSch = new JSch();
Session session=jSch.getSession(SFTPUSER,SFTPHOST,SFTPPORT);

//This is only for dev server in production will be removed
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);

//Facing issue with the below statement
jSch.addIdentity("/home/jbadmin/.ssh2/id_rsa_2048_a");

session.connect();
Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();

-----------------
-----------------
if(channel!=null) channel.disconnect(); 
if(session!=null) session.disconnect();
```

Exception:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@8c38a2
at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:747)
at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:561)
at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.newInstance(IdentityFile.java:40)
at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:407)
at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:367)
```

**Approach2:** Using [SSHJ](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/net/schmizz/sshj/examples)

```
SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient(); 
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
ssh.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier());
ssh.connect(SFTPHOST,SFTPPORT);

//Facing issue with below statements
OpenSSHKeyFile sshKeyFile = new OpenSSHKeyFile();
sshKeyFile.init("/home/jbadmin/.ssh2/id_rsa_2048_a");
ssh.authPublickey(SFTPUSER,sshKeyFile);

SFTPClient sftp = ssh.newSFTPClient();

-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
sftp.close();
ssh.disconnect();
ssh.close();
```

Exception(without using BouncyCastle):

```
INFO  [net.schmizz.sshj.common.SecurityUtils] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-6) BouncyCastle not registered, using the default JCE provider
WARN  [net.schmizz.sshj.DefaultConfig] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-6) Disabling high-strength ciphers: cipher strengths apparently limited by JCE policy
INFO  [net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-6) Client identity string: SSH-2.0-SSHJ_0_9_0
INFO  [net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-6) Server identity string: SSH-2.0-6.4.6.215 SSH Tectia Server
WARN  [net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.keyprovider.OpenSSHKeyFile] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-6) Error reading public key: net.schmizz.sshj.common.Buffer$BufferException: Underflow
INFO  [net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-6) Disconnected - BY_APPLICATION
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sgiserve].[mvc]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-6) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet mvc threw exception: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMReader$EncryptedPrivateKeyParser, method: parseObject signature: (Lorg/bouncycastle/util/io/pem/PemObject;)Ljava/lang/Object;) Incompatible argument to function
   at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader.<init>(Unknown Source) [bcpkix-jdk15on-1.49.jar:1.49.0]
   at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader.<init>(Unknown Source) [bcpkix-jdk15on-1.49.jar:1.49.0]
   at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader.<init>(Unknown Source) [bcpkix-jdk15on-1.49.jar:1.49.0]
   at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.keyprovider.PKCS8KeyFile.readKeyPair(PKCS8KeyFile.java:128) [sshj-0.9.0.jar:]
   at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.keyprovider.PKCS8KeyFile.getPublic(PKCS8KeyFile.java:72) [sshj-0.9.0.jar:]
   at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.keyprovider.OpenSSHKeyFile.getPublic(OpenSSHKeyFile.java:60) [sshj-0.9.0.jar:]
   at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.method.KeyedAuthMethod.putPubKey(KeyedAuthMethod.java:44) [sshj-0.9.0.jar:]
   at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.method.AuthPublickey.buildReq(AuthPublickey.java:62) [sshj-0.9.0.jar:]
   at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.method.AuthPublickey.buildReq(AuthPublickey.java:81) [sshj-0.9.0.jar:]
   at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.method.AbstractAuthMethod.request(AbstractAuthMethod.java:63) [sshj-0.9.0.jar:]
   at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.UserAuthImpl.authenticate(UserAuthImpl.java:68) [sshj-0.9.0.jar:]
   at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.auth(SSHClient.java:211) [sshj-0.9.0.jar:]
   at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.authPublickey(SSHClient.java:316) [sshj-0.9.0.jar:]
   at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.authPublickey(SSHClient.java:335) [sshj-0.9.0.jar:]
```

Exception(using BouncyCastle):

```
INFO  [net.schmizz.sshj.common.SecurityUtils] (http-/10.92.141.78:28080-1) BouncyCastle already registered as a JCE provider
WARN  [net.schmizz.sshj.DefaultConfig] (http-/10.92.141.78:28080-1) Disabling high-strength ciphers: cipher strengths apparently limited by JCE policy
INFO  [net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl] (http-/10.92.141.78:28080-1) Client identity string: SSH-2.0-SSHJ_0_9_0
INFO  [net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl] (http-/10.92.141.78:28080-1) Server identity string: SSH-2.0-6.4.6.215 SSH Tectia Server
ERROR [net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl] (reader) Dying because - {}: net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: Unable to reach a settlement: [] and [aes256-cbc, aes192-cbc, aes128-cbc, aes256-ctr, aes192-ctr, aes128-ctr, 3des-cbc, seed-cbc@ssh.com]
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Proposal.firstMatch(Proposal.java:165) [sshj-0.9.0.jar:]
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Proposal.negotiate(Proposal.java:147) [sshj-0.9.0.jar:]
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.KeyExchanger.gotKexInit(KeyExchanger.java:239) [sshj-0.9.0.jar:]
```

**My Private Key (id_rsa_2048_a):**

```
$ cat id_rsa_2048_a
---- BEGIN SSH2 ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY ----
Subject: xxxxx
Comment: "2048-bit rsa, xxxxx@xxxxx, Tue Dec 29 2015 11:38:\47 +0800"
------------------------
------------------------
---- END SSH2 ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY ----
```

**My Public Key(id_rsa_2048_a.pub):**

```
$cat id_rsa_2048_a.pub
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Subject: xxxxxx
Comment: "2048-bit rsa, xxxxx@xxxxxxx, Tue Dec 29 2015 11:38:\47 +0800"
---------------------
---------------------
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

**authorization file:**

```
key gwf.id_dsa_2048_a.pub
key id_rsa_2048_a.pub
```

I am not sure whether the issue with my `private key` or the way i implemented, we have already shared our `public key` to remote machine. using putty we are able to transfer file to remote machine using `SCP`.

Comment: How did you generate the private key files that you're using here?

Comment: My system administrator created the keys using [ssh-keygen-g3](https://support.ssh.com/manuals/client-user/50/ssh-keygen-g3.html).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have not loaded unlimited strength cryptography for the JVM

```
WARN  [net.schmizz.sshj.DefaultConfig] (http-/10.92.141.78:28080-1) Disabling high-strength ciphers: cipher strengths apparently limited by JCE policy
```

Please download the Java Cryptography Extensions for your JVM in order to allow high strength ciphers and keys to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I had this similar problem, it could be that your existing private key is not using open SSH format.
My solution was to convert the existing private key file using the following command:

```
ssh-keygen -i -f id_rsa_2048_a > id_rsa_2048_a_opensshformat
```

Ho